# Why does my MacBook Pro frequently add another hour to the clock

Tags: parallels-desktop, time, timezone

20 minutes ago my new MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018 - OS Version 10.14.1 (18B75)) showed that it's 10:37 and now it shows the time s 11:57 (10:57 is the correct time given that I set the timezone to `UTC+1`). What could cause this odd behvior?
I'm running a Virtual Machine of Windows 10 with Parallels Desktop that shows the same problem.
Over the cause of the day the hour gets frequently added and then again reset which is very confusing behavior.
How do I fix this?